# Intersect two arrays with different dimension

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays with different dimensions that looks like this:
Array named $form_types;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [form_type_id] => 1
            [1] => Full name
            [form_title] => Full name
            [2] => text
            [input_type] => text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [form_type_id] => 2
            [1] => Birth date
            [form_title] => Birth date
            [2] => date
            [input_type] => date
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [form_type_id] => 3
            [1] => Sex
            [form_title] => Sex
            [2] => text
            [input_type] => text
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [form_type_id] => 4
            [1] => Address
            [form_title] => Address
            [2] => text
            [input_type] => text
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [form_type_id] => 5
            [1] => City
            [form_title] => City
            [2] => select
            [input_type] => select
        )
```

And array named $_POST (array values 1 and 5 are the same as *form_type_id* in $form_types):

```
Array
(
    [1] => John Smith
    [5] => Chicago
)
```

I need to find a way the intersecting values. In this case that would be:

```
Array
(
    [1] => text
    [5] => select
)
```

I tried:

```
$arr_input_types = array_intersect($input_types, $_POST);
```

but it return zero.

And I also tried:

```
$arr_input_types = array_intersect(array_column($input_types, 'form_type_id'), array_keys($_POST));
```

but return only:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [4] => 5
)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using array_intersect? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: Yes:

    $arr_input_types = array_intersect($input_types, $_POST);

but return zero.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? The entire code?

Comment: Ok, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do it a bit too complicated for one of the standard php array functions. You can however easily do it with some loops:

```
//populate arrays
$input_types[] = array (0 => 1, "form_type_id" => 1, 1 => "Full name", "form_title" => "Full name", 2 => "text" , "input_type" => "text");
$input_types[] = array (0 => 2, "form_type_id" => 2, 1 => "Birth date", "form_title" => "Birth date", 2 => "date" , "input_type" => "date");
$input_types[] = array (0 => 3, "form_type_id" => 3, 1 => "Sex", "form_title" => "Sex", 2 => "text" , "input_type" => "text");
$input_types[] = array (0 => 4, "form_type_id" => 4, 1 => "Address", "form_title" => "Address", 2 => "text" , "input_type" => "text");
$input_types[] = array (0 => 5, "form_type_id" => 5, 1 => "City", "form_title" => "City", 2 => "select" , "input_type" => "select");

$_POST[1] = 'John Smith';
$_POST[5] = 'Chicago';

//Loop over each entry to search for
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key ){
    //Loop to the input array
    foreach ($input_types as $search){
        //If we find the right key, add it to the results array
        if ($search['form_type_id'] == $key){
            $results[$key] = $search['input_type'];
        }
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation it seems that you want, for each key `X` in the `$_POST` array:

1. find a member of `$form_types` array where a sub-member has key=`form_type_id' and value matching`X`.
2. then in the member selected at #1, find value `V` of its sub-member having key `2`.
3. in resulting array, create a member like `X => V`.

If so, try this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
  $look_for = NULL;
  foreach ($form_types as $form_type) {
    if ($form_type['form_type_id'] == $key) {
      $look_for = $form_type[2];
      break;
    }
  }
  $result[$key] = $look_for; // NULL if no match found
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the result is:

   `Array
    (
        [1] => 
        [5] => 
    )`

Comment: @JoshGandosh Sorry, there was a bug. Now edited, tested.